# Removing malware from Railo / Tomcat / Mura

Tags: tomcat, railo, mura

All,

My Mura sandbox ended up getting infected with bots which I'm trying to locate and remove.  I have a list of file names c99.php, rwwwshell.pl, sewse.cgi, sgdyname.exe.

The problem is that I've searched the filesystem with no results and dumped the database to a text file, also no results.

A webscan gave me the filenames so I've tried using some website download tools to download the entire site and try to find the files, but no dice there either.

How else can I try to find these files?

Comment: I thought about that, but since I can't find it in the first place I'm worried it'd be bundled up with the site and just end up back where it came from.

Comment: If you're not comfortable doing this yourself, it's probably best to hire a security consultant to make sure it is done properly.